# Question about modelling birdcage

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bezier-curves

[image: fancy birdcage, public domain photo]

I have been trying to model a fancy birdcage, similar to the one seen below, but I have run into a problem: I have created the bottom and the bars, the problem is I want to place the bars in a perfect circle and placing them by hand is tedious and often leads to inaccuracy. Is there any way I could, for example, place the bars along a circle curve? Or is there any other way that I could place the bars in a perfect circle?

I have not included a *.blend* file or a screenshot of my setup, because it is a very simple setup, just imagine the bottom as a default cylinder and the bars as the default bezier curve.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could use an Array modifier with an empty as object and make the empty rotate on Z so that the vertical bars replicate all arounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *mooboots* said in his comment, use the array modifier:

- Create the curve of the bars and and empty
- Make sure that both the empty and the origin of the curve sre in the center of the disk
- Apply all eventual rotation and scale of the curve and the empty
- Create an **Array Modifier** on the curve
- In the modifier, disable *Relative Offset* and enable *Object Offset*. In the field below insert the empty. There shouldn't be any visible changes
- Rotate the empty on the Z axis using a nice angle (like 5, 10 or 30 degrees) ans increase the *Count* slider in the modifier
- Done

You can still change the curve or the angle, just remember that if you want to move them you need to always move the empty and the curve together

Comment: Thank you for clarifying moonboots comment, i tried this method and it worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: No need to eyeball the rotation and array count. The angle needed for the rotation is 360° divided by the count of the array modifier. So first choose your array count (let's say 16), then in the Z rotation field, you can simply write down the math operation ```360/16```. It will do the math for you.